# More about Darboux theorem

Tags: proof-explanation

Can you explain the differences or relationships between Darboux theorem and Riemann Integral? I thought that Darboux theorem was about derivative but why internet connects this with integral? It does not have to be so profound.. Please help me. Again I'm just a high school student so can you write more easier to understand?

Comment: *Where* does the Internet connect those two concepts?

Comment: I'm not sure but sometimes it does. Is there another theorem of Darboux that can confuse  people like me?

Comment: It is the definition of definite integral by Darboux, that can be proved to be equivalent to Riemann integral: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux_integral

Comment: Oh now I understand.. So you mean that those are totally different theorem?

Comment: One of them is a theorem. The other one is a definition.

Comment: OK. Thank you.^.^